# How to make LastPass login to Yelp automatically

Tags: geolocation, lastpass, yelp.com

I noticed LastPass does not properly work with Yelp. I had set it to autologin and it didn't. The first time I tried (after already having saved the password) it filled out the login details but didn't submit, the second time I tried it didn't even automatically fill in the log in details. I think the problem may be that I connect to the internet through a VPN so it appears I'm in a different location than the pages for locations I'm trying to rate, so the login page is actually different depending on you (supposed) geographical location. For example, after logging in I somehow get redirected to http://www.yelp.ca/chicago which seems awfully strange.

So the question is how do you get LastPass to login to Yelp automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your LastPass Vault, Then to Settings > Equivalent Domains. You want to make sure the Yelp Domains you use, are considered equivalent.

This is what I added:

> yelp.com, yelp.be, yelp.ca

Apply the changes in the Settings, (requires Lastpass Master Password verification)

As for Auto Login, that only works if there is a form to AutoFill. So unless you visit the /login page first you won't auto login. You could easily login automatically by just clicking the login button.

Go straight to the login page if you want to auto login, after logon it should send you to the homepage anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I also have a problem with this page. Lastpass doesn't login http://riipen.com/students/sign_in?student=true

Comment: As user221287 mentioned, unfortunately there are some sites where auto-login doesn't seem to work. Usually when it contains lots of Javascript. I don't know why that is. Try Auto-filling the form, if that works you can try messing with the settings to try and get it to auto login.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case with a few websites. These websites have employed a system which prevents auto-login. This happens with Facebook too. Unfortunately, there is nothing that you can do about it.